# SQL server image data type value inserted is not same

Tags: sql-server, image

I am inserting a value in the table having image datatype, value inserted is not same as that inserted

```
CREATE TABLE Products(
    [Key] [nvarchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [Data] [image] NOT NULL,
)
```

I am using the below statement

```
insert into Products values( '1','0xEC7D079C1CB5F5FFFACE74')
```

> value inserted is '0x307845433744303739433143423546354646464143453734'
>   instead of '0xEC7D079C1CB5F5FFFACE74'

Is there any other way to insert an image value in the table?

Comment: FYI, the [text, ntext, and image datatypes are on the deprecation list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187993.aspx), you should avoid using them if possible, so ideally you would change your `image` column for `varbinary(max)`.

Comment: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be confusing a string with binary.

This is a string: `'0xEC7D079C1CB5F5FFFACE74'`

This is binary: `0xEC7D079C1CB5F5FFFACE74`

[Also, why do you have a integer key declared as `nvarchar(40)` ??]

As @GarethD pointed out, the [text, ntext, and image datatypes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187993.aspx) are on the deprecation list and you should avoid using them in new development work.